# How to extract the function from sympy.diff?

Tags: python, function, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to calculate a derivative function using `sympy.diff`, and then solve the `'x'` in this function letting the roots of derivative function `func(x) = 0`. However, solve this derivative function is very slow, because it returns five solutions, but I only need the solution most close to a fixed value `x0`.

```
import sympy

def diff_dist_func(a, b, c):
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    x0 = sympy.Symbol('x0')
    y0 = sympy.Symbol('y0')

    dist = ((x - x0) ** 2 + (a * x ** 3 + b * x ** 2 + c * x - y0) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
    return sympy.diff(dist, x)

a = -0.00020129919480721813
b=0.10107634020780536
c=-12.305150031126267
shortest_dist = diff_dist_func(a, b, c)
    
x0=252.3007982720215
y0=96.55526056735049
solve_shortest_dist = shortest_dist.evalf(subs={'x0': x0, 'y0': y0})  # build the derivative function
solve_x = sympy.solve(solve_shortest_dist, sympy.Symbol('x'), simplify=False, rational=False)  # Here solve the derivative function is very slow.
```

To speed up the solution, I try to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve`, which is able to give a starting estimate `x0` for the roots of `func(x) = 0`. So I replace `sympy.solve` with `fsolve(solve_shortest_dist, np.array([x0]))`, but an error occured `TypeError: 'Mul' object is not callable`. How to extract the derivative function from the output of sympy.diff, enable it to be solved by `scipy.optimize.fsolve`? Or are there any way to speed up the solving process?

Comment: To convert a sympy function into an actual Python function, you can use `sympy.lamdify`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do need the speed and want a numerical solution, [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) (`fsolve` is a legacy function, so I prefer using the newer `root` function) can work on the result of the `lambdify` function. `lambdify` converts a sympy function into a numpy or scipy function (there are options to use other packages). Once converted, the scipy root-finder can work just fine.

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

# your other code here

solve_shortest_dist_f = sympy.lambdify(sympy.Symbol("x"), solve_shortest_dist)
res = root(solve_shortest_dist_f, x0)
print(res.x[0]) # 252.30367495620214
```

The `res` variable contains some information about the solve, but `res.x[0]` is your root.

Timing this, it takes 6.01ms vs sympy solve which takes 22.2ms. Though, sympy is finding all the roots while scipy is just finding one.

Comment: Great! By the way, are there any scipy function can replace the sympy.diff? I wonder if it is possible to accelerate building the derivative function.

Comment: @xc-2021 To the best of my knowledge, using sympy to differentiate and then converting that to a function using `lambdify` is the easiest way.

Comment: @xc-2021 Though, there are special cases. Namely, polynomials. Numpy has methods for creating polynomials and finding their roots.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the SymPy 1.12, and `solve` is really fast, no need to move onto numerical libraries for now:

```py
def diff_dist_func(a, b, c):
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    x0 = sympy.Symbol('x0')
    y0 = sympy.Symbol('y0')

    dist = sympy.sqrt((x - x0) ** 2 + (a * x ** 3 + b * x ** 2 + c * x - y0) ** 2)
    return sympy.diff(dist, x)

a = -0.00020129919480721813
b = 0.10107634020780536
c = -12.305150031126267
shortest_dist = diff_dist_func(a, b, c)

x0 = 252.3007982720215
y0 = 96.55526056735049
sols = sympy.solve(shortest_dist.subs({'x0': x0, 'y0': y0}), x)
sols
# out: [-5.99737132198727,
#  76.9370574126698,
#  252.303674956197,
#  256.81160524887 - 13.1689464528248*I,
#  256.81160524887 + 13.1689464528248*I]
```

Note the complex solutions. Let's compute the error wrt `x0`:

```py
sols = np.array(sols, dtype=complex)
error = np.abs(sols - x0)
error
# out: array([2.58298170e+02, 1.75363741e+02, 2.87668418e-03, 1.39200765e+01,
       1.39200765e+01])
```

Finally, extract the closest solution to `x0`:

```py
idx = np.argmin(error)
sols[idx]
# out: 252.303674956197
```

Comment: Yes, the speed is acceptable. The `sympy.solve(shortest_dist.subs({'x0': x0, 'y0': y0}), sympy.Symbol('x'))` takes 6 seconds on my PC, also using the SymPy 1.12, but it speed up by 220ms using `sympy.solve(shortest_dist.subs({'x0': x0, 'y0': y0}), sympy.Symbol('x'), simplify=False, rational=False)`. Is there any way to speed it up to less than 100ms?  I'm now using it to a task of autonomous driving for real time application, and 220ms is a little bit slow.

Comment: I wonder how much time it takes using your PC, maybe my device influence the speed.